# Is it possible to save a record to a XML file without saving the fields separately?

Tags: xml, delphi, record

I have a big record which is consist of many fields with different types and also dynamic arrays. I want to save it to a file and then read it back. Imagine this simple record:

```
TCustomRecord = Record
   Field1 : array of integer;
   Field2  : Integer;
   Field3 : String;
end;
```

Normally I have to use something like this to save this record to a file:

```
var
   f : File of TCustomRecord;
   cr : TCustomeRecord;
 begin
   Write(f, cr);
 end;
```

But it doesn't work because of dynamic array and string type.

So the question is:

Is there a way to save (export) it to a `TXMLDocument` without going through all the fields? (I mean adding field-by-field using `addChild()`)

Comment: What do you mean by "record"?

Comment: @Chris: He means a `record` variable.

Comment: I still have NO idea what he's asking.  Flom - Try to ask your question more clearly? This is so vague I have no idea what you're asking.  Perhaps he's asking for a way to do an automatic RTTI-based streaming-to-xml without "going through" (writing code) to make the XML?

Comment: Flom, changing "XML file" to "TXMLDocument" didn't really clarify your question at all. I assume that a solution to your problem will let you avoid writing some code; can you please give an example of what kind of code you're hoping to avoid? Can you give some hypothetical code that you expect you might be able to use *instead* of whatever you have now?

Comment: Sorry for asking vaguely. I've edited the question. Hope it clarifies.

Answer (score 3):

Your XML library obviously needs to know what the fields' values are, or else it cannot serialize them, so you're going to have to go "through all the fields" at some point. Whether you do it manually or have some way of traversing your data structure automatically (like with RTTI) makes no difference. *Something* has to look at all the fields.

Comment: There is a way if a record is fixed in size. The you can just write it as a chunk of bytes that are Base64 encoded.

Comment: Mime64 encoded binary data as an XML file.  Wow. :-) Just wow.

Comment: No, @Runner, that's not true. Records are *always* fixed in size. But the record has dynamic arrays and strings. Storing those values will just get you addresses, which are useless once the current process exits or the fields are modified. And back before Flom had explained what the question was really about, a previous version of my answer explained why your suggestion is still a bad idea even if the record contains no reference types. (And whether it's base 64 or something else is irrelevant.)

Comment: @Warren, what is so strange about it. How do you serialize an image as an XML node. You serialize it as Base64 encoded stream of bytes. What is so wrong here. It is done all the time.

Comment: I think you know what I meant. Do not nitpick. If you have for instance a single field of fixed size inside a record (32 bit integer for for example) you can write a record as 32 bytes of binary data. And read it back the same way. It is the same principle that is used to stream records to streams. And yes if you have dynamic data you cannot do it. That is why I wrote that the record must be fixed in size. I do not see anything wrong here.

Answer (score 1):

I'll cautiously say "No", although I have no idea what you mean by "going through all the fields".

Another answer links to a workable way of iterating the fields in your record using RTTI.  Then you must make sure your records are not going to use any type that your RTTI-iterator code doesn't understand, or it won't get saved.

As far as "not having to call AddChild yourself", you could simply store everything in XML attributes, without any child nodes.  I don't know if you know this, but there is not only one way to map fields in a record to  possible XML content that could result.

Here's an example record:

```
TMyData = record
           Name:String;
           Age:Integer;
           Money:Double;
end;
```

If you wanted to not call AddChild at all you could just write to the attributes, producing one entity like this:

```
  <MyData  Name="Warren" Age="48" Money="100.00"   />
```

There's nobody saying you even HAVE to use child nodes:

```
  <MyData> 
    <Name>Warren</Name>
    <Age>48</Age>
    <Money>100.00<Money/>
  </MyData>
```

So it seems to me you're avoiding the fact that XML provides you lots of ways to do them, and that an MSXML DOM like API gives you more than one way to map any record to a file.